# Html2Canvas does not render my svg element (lastest version)

Tags: html, svg, printing, html2canvas

I have a roadmap with svg elements to represent links between two items like this :

[image]

the svg code looks like :

[image]

each time that i try to print to png, my links are not rendered:

[image]

My generation code is :

```
 html2canvas(
document.getElementById("roadmapPrint"),
{
  backgroundColor:null,
}
).then(function(canvas) {
    var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream"); 
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = image ;
    a.id = "tempAtoDelete"
    a.download = "filename.png";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
     a.click();
    let aToDelete = document.getElementById("tempAtoDelete");
    document.body.removeChild(aToDelete);})
```

Do you have some advices ? i read that the latest version of html2canvas library is able to manage svg elements, is it the case ?
Thank you a lot for your help,

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my issue converting all svg elements to canvas before use html2canvas librairy.
This was an old solution (6 years old) but it works fine.

See my steps below:

1. install the version 1.5.3 of canvg librairy and import the canvg function (for information this version is dowloaded more than 140000 per week..) (there is no dependence vulnerability with the last version of node/npm/CRA)

`npm install canvg@1.5.3`

`import canvg from 'canvg'`

2. get all your svg element and create a canvas for each (track them to an array to delete them after)

```
//FOR EACH SVG ELEMENT, A CANVAS WILL BE CREATED => AT THE END WE NEED TO DELETE THEM
  var svgNodesToRemove = [];

  //GET ALL SVG ELEMENT
  let svgElements = document.body.querySelectorAll('svg');

  //LOOP ON EACH ELEMENT
  svgElements.forEach(function(item) {

    //YOU CAN PROCEED TO ELEMENT TREATMENT BEFORE CONVERT TO CANVAS 
    let children = item.childNodes
    children.forEach(function(child) {

      //IN MY CASE I USE ANIMATION FOR MY SVG PATH AND NEED TO FIX THE OPACITY STYLE
      child.style.opacity = 1;
    })

    //TRIM EACH ITEM IN THE LOOP
    let svg = item.outerHTML.trim();

    //CREATE CANVAS FOR YOUR CURRENT SVG
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    //UPDATE THE NEEDED ATTRIBUTE WITH AND HEIGHT
    canvas.width = item.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    canvas.height = item.getBoundingClientRect().height;

    //CONVERT SVG TO CANVAS
    canvg(canvas, svg); 

    //UPDATE THE CANVAS POSITION TO THE SVG ELEMENT
    if (item.style.position) {
        canvas.style.position += item.style.position;
        canvas.style.left += item.style.left;
        canvas.style.top += item.style.top;
    }

    //APPEND THE CANVAS TO THE DOM
    item.parentNode.appendChild(canvas);

    //TRACK CANVAS TO BE DELTED AFTER 
    svgNodesToRemove.push(canvas)

  });
```

I did not hidde my current svg element in the dom because there are not rendered...

3. now you are able to use html2canvas :

```
html2canvas(
    document.getElementById("roadmapPrint"),
    {
      backgroundColor:null,
    }
  ).then(function(canvas){
  
      //YOUR LOGIC
      //....

      //DELETE SVG CANVAS
      svgNodesToRemove.forEach(function(element){
        element.remove();
      })

}).catch((err)=>{

    //DISPLAY ERROR
    console.log(err)

    //DELETE SVG CANVAS
    svgNodesToRemove.forEach(function(element){
      element.remove();
    })
  });
```